# new locales not showing up

Tags: localization

We have created a site with locales (English, German and Italian). We want to add an extra locale to the home page so we went into the locales admin area and added the new locale. But when we edit the home page this new locale does not show up, it seems like the locale list for a page is setup when the page is created and the new locales are only available to newly created pages.

regards

Andrew

Answer (score 2):

You have to activate the new locale in the section's settings.